# Obtaining all possible states of an object for a NP-Complete(?) problem in Python

Tags: iteration, python, combinatorics

Not sure that the example (nor the actual usecase) qualifies as NP-Complete, but I'm wondering about the most Pythonic way to do the below assuming that this was the algorithm available.

Say you have :

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self):
    self.status='unknown'
  def set(self,value):
    if value:
      self.status='happy'
    else :
      self.status='sad'
  ... blah . Maybe it's got their names or where they live or whatev.
```

and some operation that requires a group of Persons. (The key value is here whether the Person is happy or sad.)

Hence, given PersonA, PersonB, PersonC, PersonD - I'd like to end up a list of the possible 2**4 combinations of sad and happy Persons. i.e.

```
[
[ PersonA.set(true), PersonB.set(true), PersonC.set(true), PersonD.set(true)], 
[ PersonA.set(true), PersonB.set(true), PersonC.set(true), PersonD.set(false)], 
[ PersonA.set(true), PersonB.set(true), PersonC.set(false), PersonD.set(true)], 
[ PersonA.set(true), PersonB.set(true), PersonC.set(false), PersonD.set(false)], 
etc..
```

Is there a good Pythonic way of doing this? I was thinking about list comprehensions (and modifying the object so that you could call it and get returned two objects, true and false), but the comprehension formats I've seen would require me to know the number of Persons in advance. I'd like to do this independent of the number of persons.

EDIT : Assume that whatever that operation that I was going to run on this is part of a larger problem set - we need to test out all values of Person for a given set in order to solve our problem. (i.e. I know this doesn't look NP-complete right now =) ) 
any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: this has nothing whatsoever to do with NP-completeness...

Comment: yeah, NPc was probably the wrong way to describe this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you've stated in your problem, you're right -- you do need `itertools.product`, but not exactly the way you've stated.

```
import itertools
truth_values = itertools.product((True, False), repeat = 4)
people = (person_a, person_b, person_c, person_d)
all_people_and_states = [[person(truth) for person, truth in zip(people, combination)] for combination in truth_values]
```

That should be more along the lines of what you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could do it:

```
l = list()
for i in xrange(2 ** n):
    # create the list of n people
    sublist = [None] * n
    for j in xrange(n):
        sublist[j] = Person()
        sublist[j].set(i & (1 << j))
    l.append(sublist)
```

Note that if you wrote `Person` so that its constructor accepted the value, or such that the `set` method returned the person itself (but that's a little weird in Python), you could use a list comprehension. With the constructor way:

```
l = [ [Person(i & (1 << j)) for j in xrange(n)] for i in xrange(2 ** n)]
```

The runtime of the solution is `O(n 2**n)` as you can tell by looking at the loops, but it's not really a "problem" (i.e. a question with a yes/no answer) so you can't really call it NP-complete. See [What is an NP-complete in computer science?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210829/what-is-an-np-complete-problem) for more information on that front.

Comment: I agree that NPc was a wrong way to describe this. 

I'm not really grokking what i & (1 << j) is doing here... help?

I assume if I wanted PersonA, PersonB, I could modify the line that creates the Person object to instead copy the correct root Person...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cartesian product to get all possible combinations of people and states. Requires Python 2.6+

```
import itertools
people = [person_a,person_b,person_c]
states = [True,False]
all_people_and_states = itertools.product(people,states)
```

The variable *all_people_and_states* contains a list of tuples (x,y) where x is a person and y is either True or False. It will contain all possible pairings of people and states.