# P and NP complete problems

Tags: np

I am studying Automata theory.I am little confuse in How to problem is in P or NP complete problems.
I did not know understand whether P = NP ?
can someone clear my confusion about these problems.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: See this (closed) question: "[*What's “P=NP?”, and why is it such a famous question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111307/1364007)".

Comment: This is a significant subject in computer science. Do you seriously expect someone to type in an answer in five minutes? Buy the Garey / Johnson book, it is still outstanding.